# How does split method work to create PairFunction?

Tags: java, apache-spark

In this code Below there is `PairFunction` which is splitting an Array list in keys and values.

```
private static PairFunction<String,String,Integer> getNameAndAgePair() {
  return (PairFunction<String,String,Integer>) s -> 
    new Tuple2<>(
      s.split(" ")[0],
      Integer.valueOf(s.split(" ")[1]));
}
```

Please can someone explain how exactly this is working. I am unable to understand the split here, I know they are trying to create Key and Value but why is there split by space in both the Indexes.

```
Tuple2<>(s.split(" ")[0], Integer.valueOf(s.split(" ")[1]));}
```

This Code converts a JavaRDD to JavaPairRDD, this code is written in JavaSparkRDD. Basically this code covers how to create a PairRDD from a normal RDD?

```
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
        import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
        import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
        import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
        import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;

        import scala.Tuple2;

        public class PairRDDFromRegularRDD {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Pair Rdd From Regular 
            RDD").setMaster("local[*]");

            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

            List<String> inputString = Arrays.asList("Lily 23", " jack 29", "mary 29", 
            "James 8");

            JavaRDD<String> regularRDDs = sc.parallelize(inputString);

            JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> pairRDD = 
            regularRDDs.mapToPair(getNameAndAgePair());
        }

        private static PairFunction<String,String,Integer> getNameAndAgePair() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (PairFunction<String,String,Integer>) s -> new Tuple2<>(s.split(" ") 
            [0],Integer.valueOf(s.split(" ")[1]));
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to understand the split here, I know they are trying to create Key and Value but why is there split by space in both the Indexes.

I'm going to use spark-shell to explain if you don't mind.

```
scala> val s = "hello world"
s: String = hello world

// In Java you'd use s.split(" ")[0]
scala> val key = s.split(" ")(0)
key: String = hello

scala> val value = s.split(" ")(1)
value: String = world
```

In other words, `split` method splits a string into chunks by the given separator (a space in your case). Accessing 0th and 1st chunks is to access the values for the key and the value, respectively.

It's more Java / Scala than Spark actually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @Jacek. So if it was s.split(",") what would be the answer in that case? so according to you the space is just to separate ? will there be any diff if I use s.split("") --> no space within double quotes

Comment: If you changed the separator you would change the tokens (the output).